# Is it possible to map all static files or url routes of a website?

Tags: django, apache, devops, nmap

I want to make a few static files available in my server, but I don't want people to access it unless they know the exact URL.

This is meant to work like a game, solve a puzzle and move to the next phase by finding out the URL. Surely there are several similar games in the web.

- What I'm worried is if someone could just avoid the puzzle by "mapping" all the static files in a server. Is that possible?  [Assuming the puzzle solution would lead to a static file served]
- I would like to extend the same question for URL routes, is it possible to discover all the url routes of a website?
  For example I have mysite.com and mysite.com/hidden/solution.html if there are no links to the second URL, can someone get this information? [Except bruteforcing]

I'm hosting this page using AWS lightsail (django and apache). Is there something I can/need to do in the django/apache side to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to discover all the url routes of a website? [Except bruteforcing]

It's not possible without brute-forcing (or URL fuzzing) but your users can share the links, so...

---

I see two ways to do this:

**1. If users are authenticated**

If users are authenticated, then the solution is straight-forward. Save the solved puzzle ids in the database. If a user wants to view a solution, check the database to see if the user has solved the puzzle and serve the response.

**2. If users are not authenticated**

You can use some sort of cryptographically signed token. When a user solves the puzzle, you'll send them a signed token which would mean that *"This user has solved this puzzle"*. Later, when the user wants to view the solution, they'll need to send the token to view it.

See [Django's Cryptographic signing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signing/).

```
import time
from django.core.signing import Signer

signer = Signer()

token = signer.sign_object({
    'solution_id': <solution-id>, # could be the name of the html file
    'expire_at': time.time() + 900 # token expiry time (15 minutes from now) 
})

print(token) # -> 'eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiSGVsbG8hIn0:Xdc-mOFDjs22KsQAqfVfi8PQSPdo3ckWJxPWwQOFhR4'

# Send the token to the client
```

Later if a user wants to view `/solution.html`, they'll need to send the token in the url.

```
/solution.html?token=<token value>
```

In your view, you can check the token like this:

```
token = request.GET.get('token')

if not token:
    # return HTTP 403 Permission Denied

try:
    data = signer.unsign(token)
except signing.BadSignature:
    # invalid signature
    # return HTTP 403 Permission Denied

# check if token expired
if data['expire_at'] > time.time():
    # return HTTP 403

# check if token's solution_id matches the requested solution
# ...
# return the response
```

---

The drawback of this approach is that even if a user solves a puzzle, they can only view the solution until the token expires.

Comment: What about the static files, are they safe from "mapping" as well? I know some older pages you usually can even access the static directory as a folder. Not sure if I need to config apache to prevent that or if it's default. Thanks @xyres

Comment: @Justcurious Maybe `X-Sendfile` can be useful for restricting staticfiles access. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631585/xsendfile-with-apache-and-django

Comment: I don't really want to restrict it, they can be public available. I don't mind if people share the url, I just don't want someone to scan/map the static files and just find it there.